# My settings still showing up

Tags: permissions, personalization

I have all three unchecked for special permission. But "My Settings" still shows up. I rather not mess with the CSS unless I have to.

Personal Permissions

- Manage Personal Views  -  Create, change, and delete personal views of lists.
- Add/Remove Personal Web Parts  -  Add or remove personal Web Parts on a Web Part Page.
- Update Personal Web Parts  -  Update Web Parts to display personalized information.